# Creating matrix from a collection of dataframes according to months

Tags: r

I have data stored as a collection of data-frames named A,B,C,...

```
A <- structure(list(Mes = c("Feb 2015", "Jun 2015", "Jul 2015", "Aug 2015", "Sep 2015", "Oct 2015", "Nov 2015"), Valor = c(73.98, 1013.21, 3209.38, 4168.41, 5233.48, 1313.83, 622.78)), .Names = c("Mes","Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7"))

B <- structure(list(Mes = c("Aug 2015", "Sep 2015", "Oct 2015"), Valor = c(1391.72, 761.15, 107.58)), .Names = c("Mes", "Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

C <- structure(list(Mes = c("Aug 2015"), Valor = c(0)), .Names = c("Mes", "Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1"))
```

Note: C is being used to represent an empty data-frame

The problem is to build a matrix like:

```
"Feb 2015" "Jun 2015" "Jul 2015" "Aug 2015" "Sep 2015" "Oct 2015" "Nov 2015"
"73.98"  "1013.21"  "3209.38"  "4168.41"  "5233.48"  "1313.83"   "622.78"
    0        0          0      "1391.72"  "761.15"   "107.58"        0
    0        0          0          0         0          0            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list`, use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to create a single data.table, and reshape from 'long' to 'wide' using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
dcast(rbindlist(list(A,B))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes], ind~Mes, 
                value.var='Valor', fill=0)
#   ind Aug 2015 Feb 2015 Jul 2015 Jun 2015 Nov 2015 Oct 2015 Sep 2015
#1:   1  4168.41    73.98  3209.38  1013.21   622.78  1313.83  5233.48
#2:   2  1391.72     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00   107.58   761.15
```

In the devel version i.e. v1.9.7, we can also use `rowid` to create the sequence column

```
dcast(rbindlist(list(A, B)), rowid(Mes)~Mes, value.var='valor', fill=0)
```

#### Update

Using the new datasets

```
 DT <- rbindlist(list(A, B,C))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes]
 dcast(DT, ind~Mes, value.var='Valor', fill=0)
  #    ind Aug 2015 Feb 2015 Jul 2015 Jun 2015 Nov 2015 Oct 2015 Sep 2015
  #1:   1  4168.41    73.98  3209.38  1013.21   622.78  1313.83  5233.48
  #2:   2  1391.72     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00   107.58   761.15
  #3:   3     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
```

---

If we need a `matrix` output, this can be also done with `base R` options.  We create the sequence column using `ave` and then reshape with `xtabs`.

```
df1 <- transform(do.call(rbind, list(A, B)), ind= ave(seq_along(Mes), Mes, FUN=seq_along))
xtabs(Valor~ind+Mes, df1)
#   Mes
#ind Aug 2015 Feb 2015 Jul 2015 Jun 2015 Nov 2015 Oct 2015 Sep 2015
#  1  4168.41    73.98  3209.38  1013.21   622.78  1313.83  5233.48
#  2  1391.72     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00   107.58   761.15
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(Mes = c("Feb 2015", "Jun 2015", "Jul 2015", "Aug 2015", 
"Sep 2015", "Oct 2015", "Nov 2015"), Valor = c(73.98, 1013.21, 
3209.38, 4168.41, 5233.48, 1313.83, 622.78)), .Names = c("Mes", 
"Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7"))

B <- structure(list(Mes = c("Aug 2015", "Sep 2015", "Oct 2015"), Valor = c(1391.72, 
761.15, 107.58)), .Names = c("Mes", "Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: Do you how can I add empty data-frames as rows of zeros?

Comment: @user3083324  If it is empty dataframe, how can it can have 0s.  Sorry, didn't understand your comment.

Comment: If the dataframe has only one record, `dcast(rbindlist(list(A,B))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes], ind~Mes, value.var='Valor', fill=0)` will fill the other elements of the correspoding row with zeros

Comment: @user3083324 I haven't tested on those cases.  You can test that with an example data.

Comment: I tested it, it doesn't work let `C <- structure(list(Mes = c(), Valor = c()), .Names = c("Mes", "Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c())`, then `rbindlist(list(A,B))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes]` is the same as `rbindlist(list(A,B,C))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes]`

Comment: @user3083324  You don't have any rows in 'C'.  So, there is no 3rd row.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm thinking if there's a workaround or another solution.

Comment: One way is to substitute empty dataframes for 
`structure(list(Mes = c("Aug 2015"), Valor = c(0)), .Names = c("Mes", "Valor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1"))`

Comment: One thing I noticed is that on your solution `DT <- rbindlist(list(A, B,C))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes]` is different from `DT <- rbindlist(list(C, B, A))[, ind:= 1:.N, Mes]`, meaning that the second operation doesn't work